# More than one form validation run statement

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get two form validation run statement in my project.First I want to check my select box value. If its space, then I am getting an error message. Here I also want to get a validation if the select box value is 'Other', Then I want to check the value in the text box. Is it possible.
Ie, I want to execute two form validation run statement.If first run statement is true, I have to check with the second run statement.

Comment: please provide with more details like your validation code, the exact output you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason you can't set some rules, run validation, then set some more rules and then run validation again.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    // Do whatever you do on fail
} else {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        // do whatever you do on the 2nd fail
    }
    // do whatever you do on success
}
```